# External monitor has stopped being detected Ubunbtu 20.04.2

Tags: external-monitor

RESOLVED

I am using an Asus-UX560UQK laptop with Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS installed connected by USB to a Targus ACP70EU docking station which in turn has a Lenovo external monitor attached via the DVI port.

This setup recently stopped working in terms of the external monitor is no longer being detected.

I have gone through untold Google searches and tried all sorts of recommendations and nothing has fixed this.

The docking station also has the mouse, keyboard, and network cable attached, all of which are functioning as normal.

Please can I request some advice as to what to try?

Comment: Maybe you need to reinstall the DisplayLink drivers?

Comment: Thank you @ChanganAuto that worked.